RabbitMQ copying messages from one Queue to another
I have some messages stuck in one Queue and I want to exactly copy them (not moving) to other Queue without retriggering, is this possible in RabbitMQ?
The only option I found was to move messages using shovel management but nothing for copying

Would you be satisfied if the messages were consumed but then published back into the original queue, while also being published to a new queue?

I will like to try that, can you provide the approach
